# Can php filter words in a string while converting the remainder of the string

Tags: php

I am using this function in my form to handle text conversion.  This is an internal (workplace) web form.  It converts

> main st./grand ave. -> Main St./Grand Ave.
>   apt. #a1 -> Apt. #A1
>   1234 w. main st (childrens park) -> 1234 W. Main St (Childrens Park)
>   smith-o'rourke -> Smith-O'Rourke
>   mcbride-macgregor -> McBride-MacGregor
>   macias-machado -> MacIas-MacHado.

Hence, my problem!!

How do I include a filter list of names or words that should not be converted, such as Macias, Macayo, Machado, Mack, machine, etc.?

```
function uc_names($name_text) {
    $name_text = strtolower($name_text);
    $name_text = join("#", array_map('ucwords', explode("#", $name_text)));
    $name_text = join("/", array_map('ucwords', explode("/", $name_text)));
    $name_text = join("(", array_map('ucwords', explode("(", $name_text)));
    $name_text = join("'", array_map('ucwords', explode("'", $name_text)));
    $name_text = join("-", array_map('ucwords', explode("-", $name_text)));
    $name_text = join("Mc", array_map('ucwords', explode("Mc", $name_text)));
    $name_text = join("Mac", array_map('ucwords', explode("Mac", $name_text)));
    return trim($name_text);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that without having an exhaustive list of "Mac" names. I suggest you to forget this idea to uppercase Mac names.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not give in that easily.

Comment: I would tend to agree with @Colin. However, the only thought was that perhaps the list of 'mac' names that required conversion was smaller than the (possibly endless) list of names that didn't?! So, reversing the logic of your filter?

Comment: It gets harder when you consider that certain 'mac' names are valid either way eg. 'Macdonald' and 'MacDonald' could both be OK.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$bar = 'HELLO WORLD!';
$bar = ucwords($bar);             // HELLO WORLD!
$bar = ucwords(strtolower($bar)); // Hello World!
```

Or something in this direction?

```
function ucsmart($text)
{
   return preg_replace('/([^a-z]|^)([a-z])/e', '"$1".strtoupper("$2")', strtolower($text));
}
```

I haven't test the second one

Comment: However, I think the problem is the conversion of specific words containing "mac", not the generic upper casing of words.

Comment: You are correct.  The problem is with "Mac".  MacBride is fine, but I do not want the word "machine" changed to MacHine when it is "Steve's Machine Shop".  Same goes for the name Machado, not MacHado.

Comment: Look the very last post in this link. I think it does what you are looking for http://www.navioo.com/php/docs/function.ucwords.php